# Solr 4.3.0 Http Status 500

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, solr, dataimporthandler

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I just upgraded my system from using Solr 1.4 to Solr 4.3.0 and can't seem to get the MySQL driver to work (or so I suspect).  Solr seems to work fine (accessing it through the browser, etc) until I add the following lines to the solrconfig.xml

```
    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">/opt/solr/core01/conf/data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

After adding those lines into the config, restart Tomcat7 and refreshing my localhost:8080/solr, I get the following error:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'core01' is not available due to init failure: org/apache/solr/util/plugin/SolrCoreAware,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
    SolrCore 'core01' is not available due to init failure: org/apache/solr/util/plugin/SolrCoreAware at
```

And then a bunch of misc. filters, etc.  I only see this error via the browser - I can't seem to find it in any of the logs for Tomcat.

Another thing to note is that I have included the required JAR files for the:

```
    solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.3.0.jar
    solr-dataimporthandler-4.3.0.jar
```

as they seem to not come with the download for Solr 4.3.0

This problem has caused so much time to be wasted so hopefully someone on here can lend a hand and see what is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is what my data-config.xml looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataConfig>
      <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name" user="db_user" password="db_password" />
      <document>
        <entity name="table" query="SELECT * FROM table">
          <field column="id" name="id" />
          <field column="name" name="name" />
        </entity>
      </document>
    </dataConfig>
```

With the obvious variables replaced with real data.

Comment: whats the full stack trace for the exceptions ? also did you include the mysql driver jar in the solr core lib ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the [DIHQuickStart page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart) and looking at the error meessage, you might want to remove the path from your `config` setting, as Solr will look in the conf folder of the core where you have defined the DIH first by default. So change it to:

```
 <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Removing the absolute path did nothing.  It shouldn't have made a difference.  I still have the same error even after restarting Tomcat.  Any other ideas?